# Recursive call is corrupting my data?

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm calling this function to load a TreeView with a list of the directories on the disk.

```
private void LoadDirectories(string currentPath, TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentPath);
    DirectoryInfo[] directories = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directories)
    {
        if ((dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != FileAttributes.System &&
            (dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = nodes.Add(dir.Name);
            LoadDirectories(dir.FullName, newNode.Nodes);
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out the recursive call I get all of the subdirectories in the tree.  If I don't I don't. Some directories are missing.  I'm not sure what is going on.

Help?

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Using this example code it works just fine. I recommend you use this as a starting point.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var n = LoadDirectory(@"E:\Share");
    Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static Node LoadDirectory(string path)
{
    var n = new Node() { Name = path };
    LoadDirectories(path, n);
    return n;
}

private static void LoadDirectories(string currentPath, Node node)
{
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentPath);
    DirectoryInfo[] directories = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in directories)
    {
        if ((dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != FileAttributes.System &&
            (dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
        {
            var n = new Node() { Name = dir.Name };
            node.Children.Add(n);
            LoadDirectories(dir.FullName, n);
        }
    }
}

private class Node
{
    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
    public string Name;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(1);
    }

    public string ToString(int depth)
    {
        if (Children.Count == 0)
        {
            return Name;
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder(Name);
        foreach (var n in Children)
        {
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.Append("".PadLeft(depth, '\t') + n.ToString(depth + 1));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem wasn't with the recursive call at all.  The problem was that the `GetDirectories` call was throwing an `AccessDenied` exception if the current user didn't have access to the requested directory.

I simply wrapped the appropriate calls in a try/catch block and all is well.

Thanks for your help Chaos!